# how to access/modify system files in android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-11

I am creating basic app with SQlite database and I want to put export and import button in application but Google is trying to prevent apps from accessing external storage in android 11 for privacy concerns and my target devices are running android 11.

what I tried,

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

but i came to know that it only works till android 10.
I tried to access files from android studio's devices file explorer, it also not letting me into sys/emulated/0

how to backup files?

how can i export my sqlite.db file to my phones storage.

if i uses normal methods it throws error

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Members.DB: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
2021-06-11 16:04:46.164 17000-17000/com.shashank.managemembers W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
2021-06-11 16:04:46.164 17000-17000/com.shashank.managemembers W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
2021-06-11 16:04:46.164 17000-17000/com.shashank.managemembers W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:125)
2021-06-11 16:04:46.164 17000-17000/com.shashank.managemembers W/System.err:     at com.shashank.managemembers.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:173)
```

Comment: Copy to for instance public Documents directory.

Comment: Copy them to a filesystem location that you have write access to, such as those provided by methods on `Context` (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`). Or, ask the user for a location via `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and write the content to that location. [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.5/ImportExport) (profiled in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room)) demonstrates the second approach, for both export/backup and import/restore operations. Note that the sample uses Room and is written in Kotlin.